# Jquery with mouseover that works only on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

i'm having some difficulty with the jquery mouseover.

I simply want to have the distortion effect happen when the mouse hovers over the image, and not when the mouse leaves.  I am using mgGlitch for the effect and using jquery for the hover.  I appreciate the help!

JQUERY

```
$(".glitch-img").hover(function() {
    $( ".glitch-img" ).mgGlitch({
      // set 'true' to stop the plugin
              destroy : false,
      // set 'false' to stop glitching
      glitch: true,
      // set 'false' to stop scaling
      scale: true,
      // set 'false' to stop glitch blending
      blend : true,
      // select blend mode type
      blendModeType : 'hue',
      // set min time for glitch 1 elem
      glitch1TimeMin : 200,
      // set max time for glitch 1 elem
      glitch1TimeMax : 400,
      // set min time for glitch 2 elem
      glitch2TimeMin : 10,
      // set max time for glitch 2 elem
      glitch2TimeMax : 100,
    }),


    // .mouseout(function() {
    //      $(".glitch-img").myGlitch({
    //          // set 'true' to stop the plugin
    //                destroy : false,
    //          // set 'false' to stop glitching
    //          glitch: false,
    //          // set 'false' to stop scaling
    //          scale: false,
    //          // set 'false' to stop glitch blending
    //          blend : false,
    // })
```

});

Answer (score 0):

From the [JQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

What you want to do instead is bind the event to the `mouseover()` function. [Reference](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)